# How to capture an hour long video on a Worker in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-workmanager, video-recording

I am writing an app to record a video at a predefined time. (Note this app is only for personal use. I will put the phone in a remote location and it should record an 1h video at predefined times every day) The record is planned using a worker to make sure the task is performed even if the device is in sleep.

I got the Worker implemented and it executes nicely at the defined times. However I am having issues recording a video in this thread. I wanted to use the CameraX API but this requires a lifecycleobject which I don't know how to access in the Worker class. That's why I am using the camera2 API now using a MediaRecorder. But I am getting the -22 error on recorder.start(). Does anyone know how to fix it or can recommend a better approach? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code in my MainActivity.kt

```
package com.android.example.workerrecordingscheduler

import android.Manifest
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.work.*

import com.android.example.workerrecordingscheduler.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val eventTimes = listOf(
        Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            set(Calendar.YEAR, 2023)
            set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH)
            set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17)
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        }
//        Calendar.getInstance().apply {
//            set(Calendar.YEAR, 2023)
//            set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH)
//            set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10)
//            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18)
//            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20)
//            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
//        },
//        Calendar.getInstance().apply {
//            set(Calendar.YEAR, 2023)
//            set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH)
//            set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10)
//            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18)
//            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
//            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
//        },
//        Calendar.getInstance().apply {
//            set(Calendar.YEAR, 2023)
//            set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY)
//            set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10)
//            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18)
//            set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50)
//            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
//        }
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (!allPermissionsGranted()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        // Permission variables
        val hasStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            applicationContext,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
        val hasCameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            applicationContext,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        )
        val hasMicPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            applicationContext,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        )
        val hasReadStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            applicationContext,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)


        if (hasStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            hasCameraPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            hasMicPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            hasReadStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permissions are granted, start the worker
            Log.d(TAG, "Permissions all granted")

        } else {
            // Permissions are not granted, request them
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ),
                REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }


        viewBinding.startButton.setOnClickListener(){myWork()}
    }

    private fun myWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Lets start")
        val lifecycleOwner = this
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        workManager.cancelAllWork()

        for (eventTime in eventTimes) {
            val now = Calendar.getInstance()
            if (now.before(eventTime)) {
                val delay = eventTime.timeInMillis - now.timeInMillis

                val data = Data.Builder()
                    .putLong("eventTime", eventTime.timeInMillis)
                    .build()


                val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(RecordingWorker::class.java)
                    .setInputData(data)
                    .setInitialDelay(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build()

                val uniqueWorkName = "record_${eventTime.timeInMillis}"

                workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
                    uniqueWorkName,
                    ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,  // Replace previous work request with the same name
                    workRequest

                )
            }
        }
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXApp"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS =
            mutableListOf (
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            ).apply {
            }.toTypedArray()
    }
}
```

My Worker looks like this (I know the video does not record for an hour yet):

```
package com.android.example.workerrecordingscheduler

import android.Manifest
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.ImageFormat
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.HandlerThread
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import java.io.File
import java.lang.Thread.sleep


class RecordingWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {

        // Put the camera operation on a separate thread
        val handlerThread = HandlerThread("CameraHandlerThread")
        handlerThread.start()
        val handler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)

        // Enable camera manager
        val cameraManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager

        // Get the list of available cameras
        val cameraIds = cameraManager.cameraIdList

        // Select the back camera (or front camera if there is no back camera)
        var cameraId = cameraIds[0]

        // Check if all required permissions are granted
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permissions granted")
        }

        cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera is opened")

                    //val builder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD).build()

                    // Get the directory for the user's public videos
                    val outputDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
                    // Create a new file in the directory with a unique name
                    val outputFile = File(outputDir, "myvideo_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4")

                    camera.close()  // close to make sure the recorder doesn't crash because the camera is opened

                    val recorder = MediaRecorder(applicationContext)
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT)
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
                    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
                    recorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.absolutePath)
                    recorder.prepare()
                    recorder.setOnErrorListener {_, what, extra ->
                        Log.e(TAG, "MediaRecorder error: what=$what, extra=$extra")
                    }

                    recorder.start()
                    recorder.stop()
                }

                override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera is disconnected")
                }

                override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, p1: Int) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera has an error")
                    camera.close() // close the camera device on error
                }
            }, handler)
        return Result.success()
    }
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WorkerRecordingScheduler"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```